# Append a line to file when blank line appears

Tags: java, string, file

Input:

```
 apple
 banana
 grapes

 apple
 banana
 grapes

 apple
 banana
 grapes
```

Expected Output:

```
 apple
 banana
 grapes
 orange
 melon

 apple
 banana
 grapes
 orange
 melon

 apple
 banana
 grapes
 orange
 melon
```

Code:

```
  String newLine=null;
  PrintStream output = new PrintStream(outputFile);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outputFile));
        while((newLine=br.readLine())!=null && !newLine.isEmpty()){
            if(!newLine.contains("orange")){
                    output.println("orange");

            }
            if(!newLine.contains("melon")){
                    output.println("orange");

            }


        }
        out.close();
        br.close();
```

The code above given for your reference appends the new strings at the end of file.But i want to append it after every record.
Please suggest me the modifications.
What do I need to do in this case?

Comment: This is a bad question in my opinion because you did not list every use case which a solution has to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon you read an empty line you need to output your `orange` and `melon` line. And additional when you reach the end of the file.

Find a snippet where you could start with.

**create an new file with the addtional llines**

```
String newLine;
try (PrintStream output = new PrintStream("fruits.out");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fruits.in"))) {
    while ((newLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // reached an empty line
        if (newLine.isEmpty()) {
            output.println("orange");
            output.println("melon");
        }
        output.println(newLine);
    }
    // reached end of file
    output.println("orange");
    output.println("melon");
}
```

**modify the input file**

```
Path fileInOut = Paths.get("fruits.in");
Charset defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset();
List<String> linesIn = Files.readAllLines(fileInOut, defaultCharset);
List<String> linesOut = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : linesIn) {
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        linesOut.add("orange");
        linesOut.add("melon");
    }
    linesOut.add(line);
}
linesOut.add("orange");
linesOut.add("melon");
Files.write(fileInOut, linesOut, defaultCharset, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: You are missing a newline after printing `"melon"` at the end of each block.

Comment: what is fruits.out and fruits.in ? I dont want to use other file. I want to use a single input file which needs to be modified. No extra output file needed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No. I still print alway the line which was read from the file. Including the empty lines.

Comment: @PS. It was not requested to change the original file. Tought it was an typo. What size the input file have?

Comment: @Sub I tried your code but it over-writes the file with orange and melon

Comment: size will be upto 200kbs. not more than that

Comment: @PS. Find a second snippet which modify the input file.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter the line containing `"grapes"` you need to append a new line for `"orange"` and `"melon"`.  Try using this code:

```
String newLine = null;
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(outputFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outputFile));
    while((newLine=br.readLine())!=null) {
        output.println(newLine);
        if (newLine.contains("grapes")) {
                output.println("orange");
                output.println("melon");
        }
    }
out.close();
br.close();
```

Comment: The last line i.e grapes is not constant. It may get change. So it is not correct solution

Comment: Who said the last line "grapes" isn't constant?  Can you point me to the place in the OP where this is stated?

Comment: Have not tried. But your code will stop after the first empty line `&& !newLine.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @tim it is just a sample input. Input can be anything.

Comment: @PS. The purpose of SO isn't always to come up with a general solution, it's to solve the exact problem at hand.

Comment: @tim you are right. But still no required solution I m getting

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.replaceAll`

```
string.replaceAll("(?s)(?:\\n\\n|$)", "\\norange\\nmelon\\n\\n");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jU1vH0/1)